# How to upload file to a form on front end Angular with backend API Rest Full (FosRestBundle,Nelmio) Symfony backend?

Tags: angularjs, symfony

I want to upload a file and others data with a form front end (angular 2 / $http.post) with my api backend (symfony 2 - fosrestbundle, nelmios doc).

I have not problem when i make a "http.post" with data but when i have a file input, i don't know how develop this.

When i test with Nelmio Doc that's work. And i want upload my file with my backend. But when i want send the data with my front end....File parameter is defined "null" of my backend.

**Have you a solution or ideas ????** 
Thx

**THE FRONT END CODE - ANGULAR2**

`app.controller('MyFormCtrl', function ($scope, Upload, $http) {
        console.log("Page Controller reporting for duty.");`

```
    $scope.username = null;
    $scope.firstname = null;
    $scope.lastname = null;
    $scope.email = null;
    $scope.mobilephone = null;
    $scope.gender = null;
    $scope.source = null;
    $scope.zipcode = null;
    $scope.file = null;


    $scope.createNew = function (username, firstname, lastname, email, mobilephone, gender, source, zipcode, file) {
        var data = {
            username: username,
            firstname: firstname,
            lastname: lastname,
            email: email,
            mobilephone: mobilephone,
            gender: gender,
            source: source,
            zipcode: zipcode,
            file: file
        };
        //Call the services
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://bend.exemple.com/web/app_dev.php/api/v1/new/exemples.json',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (response.data)
                $scope.msg = "Post Data Submitted Successfully!";
        }, function (response) {
            $scope.msg = "Service not Exists";
            $scope.statusval = response.status;
            $scope.statustext = response.statusText;
            $scope.headers = response.headers();
        });
    };
});`
```

**THE BACK END CODE - SF2 FOSRESTBUNDLE & NELMIOS DOC**

```
 /**
 * Create a Exemple from the submitted data.<br/>
 *
 * @ApiDoc(
 *   resource = true,
 *   description = "Creates a new eemple from the submitted data.",
 *   statusCodes = {
 *     200 = "Returned when successful",
 *     400 = "Returned when the form has errors"
 *   }
 * )
 *
 * @param ParamFetcher $paramFetcher Paramfetcher
 *
 * @RequestParam(name="email", nullable=false, strict=true, description="Email.")
 * @RequestParam(name="firstname", nullable=false, strict=true, description="Firstname.")
 * @RequestParam(name="lastname", nullable=false, strict=true, description="Lastname.")
 * @RequestParam(name="mobilephone", nullable=false, strict=true, description="Mobilephone.")
 * @RequestParam(name="gender", nullable=false, strict=true, description="Gender.")
 * @RequestParam(name="source", strict=true, description="Source.")
 * @RequestParam(name="zipcode", nullable=false, strict=true, description="Zipcode.")
 * @FileParam(name="file", requirements={"mimeTypes"="application/pdf", "maxSize"="10M"}, strict=true)
 *
 * @return View
 */
public function postExempleAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
{
    $exemple = new exemple();

    $exemple->setEmail($paramFetcher->get('email'));
    $exemple->setFirstname($paramFetcher->get('firstname'));
    $exemple->setLastname($paramFetcher->get('lastname'));
    $exemple->setMobilephone($paramFetcher->get('mobilephone'));
    $exemple->setGender($paramFetcher->get('gender'));
    $exemple->setSource($paramFetcher->get('source'));
    $exemple->setZipcode($paramFetcher->get('zipcode'));
    $exemple->setFile($paramFetcher->get('file'));

    // $file stores the uploaded PDF file
    /** @var Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file */
    $file = $exemple->getFile();

    $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

     $file->move(
         $this->getParameter('exemple_directory'), $fileName
     );

    $view = View::create();

    $errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($exemple, array('Registration'));

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($exemple);
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush($exemple);
        $view->setData($exemple)->setStatusCode(200);
        return $view;
    } else {
        $view = $this->getErrorsView($errors);
        return $view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

header 'application/json' works fine for data, but you have to change it if you want to send files.

You can install ng-file-upload. It will help you to send data and files to your backoffice

http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-file-upload

In youir controller, you will be able to get your file from the request :

```
$file = $this->getRequest()->files->get('file');
```

**EDIT : more details**

**HTML**

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="upload(file)">
    <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="file" name="file" >
    <button type="submit" class="button">Valider</button>
</form>
```

In your controller, add the "Upload" module and implement the upload function
**JS**

```
$scope.upload = function(file) {
Upload.upload({
    url: 'your/url/to/fosrest/rest/api',
    data: {file: file, 'anotherData': "Hello"}
}).then(function (response) {

}, function (response) {

});


}
```

In your Controller :

```
public function postYourAction(Request $request)
{
    $uploadedFile = $request->files->get('file');
    $directory = __DIR__.'../../../../web/uploads/';
    $uploadedFile->move($directory, $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName());

    $file = fopen($directory.$uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName(), 'r');
    $data = $request->request->all();



    fclose($file);
}
```

I hope it will help you

EDIT 2 : network debug
General :

```
Request URL:http://yourUrl
Request Method:POST
```

Request header :

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2007
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryLjx3EGTnnC8n15jG
Cookie:PHPSESSID=it0qh4odmm053a61ticlg1fc27
Host: ...
Origin:http://yourSite
Pragma:no-cache
...
```

Request payload :

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryLjx3EGTnnC8n15jG
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel


------WebKitFormBoundaryLjx3EGTnnC8n15jG
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mydata"

testData
```

Comment: Thx. I try with ng-file-upload .. Do u have an example ? Because it's not really explicit in the doc of ng-file-upload for me.

Comment: I have this message when i change Content-Type to "undefined":

code:400 message:"Parameter "email" of value "" violated a constraint "This value should not be null.""

My controller know theses parameters only when the Content-Type is application/json... and with this the file doesn't communicate with my api.

Why ?

Comment: OR I have this message 
code:500
message:"Unable to find template ""."

Comment: Do you use ng-file-upload ?